# Failed to lazily initialize a collection when calling size() on a lazily loaded list

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

We're using spring-data jpa with hibernate implementation.

I have a parent entity that has a list of children. The fetch type is lazy.      When I call the find method in my service class. I get the parent object back but doing size() on the list of children gives me Lazy exception:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Shouldn't I be able to do size() on the lazily loaded list since my find method has @Transacitonal annotation on it?

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="PARENT")
    public class Parent implements Serializable{

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Child.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="pk", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private List<Child> children;

 }


    @Entity
    @Table(name="CHILD")
    public class Child implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3574595532165407670L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "pk")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="childPK_GENERATOR", sequenceName="childseq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="childPK_GENERATOR")
    private Long pk;
 }
```

**Service class:**

```
@Transactional
     public Parent find(Lond id){
        Parent parent = parentRepository.findOne(id)
        parent.getChildren.size(); //throws lazy load exception
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Transactional will wrap your method invocation in a transaction only if you **have configured** Spring Transaction Manager.

Suppose you have configured your JPA with java config file.

```
@Import(TransactionConfig.class)
public class JpaConfig {
// your EntityManagerFactory configs...
}
```

Then you should configure transaction manager

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionConfig {

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
    }
}
```

Comment: We do have the spring transaction manager enabled. We're not using java config but xml config to do so in this way:
`<tx:annotation-driven />`

Comment: @Nero When you get lazy initialization exception it means that your entity `parent` is in **detached** state. -> That means **persistent context is closed**, after method `parentRepository.findOne(id)` invocation. -> Therefore, **no spring transaction** was created around invocation of method `find`. _Thus, transaction manager isn't enabled, or it's configs are incorrect_